# Exsheets print subsection counter?

Tags: numbering, counters, exsheets

When defining a counter format in `exsheets` I can use `ch` for chapter, `se` for section or`qu` for question. But how can I reference to the subsection counter?

I can do:

```
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={subsection},counter-format=se.qu}
```

but I want something like

```
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={subsection},counter-format=se.sub.qu}
```

where sub referes to the subsection counter.

Comment: It would be super awesome to help, but I don't know `exsheets`... and with the code snippet, I can't really get anything up-and-running to test it out. Would you be able to supply a minimal example?

Comment: did you try `counter-format=subsection.qu`

Comment: or my be  `counter-format={subsection}.qu`?

Comment: @touhami: Doesn't work, it just enters the word "subsection".

Comment: `sse.qu` should do

Comment: @clemens this just adds an s before the subsection number

Comment: @student Ah, you must add a pattern before: `\AddCounterPattern*[exsheets]{subsection}{sse}`

Comment: @clemens Doesn't seem to have any effect. Furhermore I cannot find `\AddCounterPattern*` in the documentation.

Comment: @student it's `\AddCounterPattern` without the star. And use a pattern that doesn't contain `se`, e.g., `sub`. The `exsheets` package uses the `cntformats` package for those patterns. The command is described in the corresponding manual.

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow when I have a computer with a TeX installation available and will add an answer then.

Comment: @clemens: Without a star and using `sub` works but only for the question. The solution numbers doesn't match anymore.

Comment: @student that's what I feared. An update to `exsheets` might be necessary. But as I said: I'll look into it.

Comment: @student sorry it took me so long: I just sent the update to CTAN. The new version should be available in TL and MiKTeX in a few days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question led me to some long overdue changes in `exsheets`. The new version v0.21c (not yet on CTAN but [available here for the impatient](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/src/)) gives you three possibilities (including [the one proposed by @touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299941/)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2016/03/21]
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = subsection ,
  counter-format = \thesubsection.qu
}

% or:
% \renewcommand*\thequestion{\thesubsection.\arabic{question}}
% \SetupExSheets{
%   counter-within = subsection ,
%   counter-format = \thequestion
% }

% or:
% \AddCounterPattern[exsheets]{subsection}{sbs}
% \SetupExSheets{
%   counter-within = subsection ,
%   counter-format = se.sbs.qu
% }

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{question}
  Yes?
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  No!
\end{solution}

\subsection{bla}
\begin{question}
  Yes?
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  No!
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Yes?
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  No!
\end{solution}

\section{Last}
\subsection{bla}
  \begin{question}
  Yes?
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  No!
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. with

```
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={subsection},counter-format=\thesubsection.qu}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={subsection},counter-format=\thesubsection.qu}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{question}
Yes?
\end{question}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{question}
Yes?
\end{question}
\begin{question}
Yes?
\end{question}
\section{Last}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{question}
Yes?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work if you print the solutions in another section. Then the numbers of solutions and questions doesn't match anymore.

Comment: @student I will see.