# Use question counter for numbering equations in solutions that appear at end of document

Tags: numbering, exsheets

I'm using `exsheets` for writing problem sets. I want to number equations by question to which they pertain. So I use `\numberwithin{equation}{question}`.

This works well for equations that appear within the question itself, but not solutions (which I'm printing at the end).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\numberwithin{equation}{question}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
First Question
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
Second Question
\end{question}

\section*{Answers}%
\printsolutions%

\end{document}
```

[image]

I was expecting "a^2+b^2=c^2 to be numbered as 1.2.

All solution equations use the last question number as their number. How can I use the appropriate question number within the solution?

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299898/exsheets-print-subsection-counter

Comment: Try adding `\renewcommand\theequation{\CurrentQuestionID.\arabic{equation}}` and `\SetupExSheets{solution/pre-body-hook = \setcounter{equation}{0}}` (this might not play well with `hyperref`, though…)

Comment: @clemens That gets the question number correct, but you're right it makes references point to the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is adding tags; this might perhaps be made automatic provided you just use `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\numberwithin{equation}{question}
\NewDocumentCommand{\TAG}{m}{\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
First Question
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \TAG{A}
\end{equation}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2 \TAG{A}
    \end{equation}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
Second Question
\end{question}

\section*{Answers}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\TAG}{m}{\tag{\ref{#1}}}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]